# Django OpenID django-openid-auth Login Error

Tags: python, django, openid

I get the following error when attempting to use django-openid-auth `OpenID discovery error: No usable OpenID services found for *******@gmail.com`

I have followed the instructions that come with it, though it seems there is something I am missing. the installation is on my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supplying an email address or URL? OpenID needs a URL and `*******@gmail.com` is an email address.